# How to prove unsolvable problem for Turinh machine?

Tags: turing-machines

Lets prove that problem cannot to be algorithmically solved: B(M) = 1, if M - Turing Machine program and there does not have any input for string length 2, 4, 6, 8, on which M stops

My idea is:

M = “On input string w:.

1. Scan the tape and mark the first 0 which has not been marked. If no unmarked 0 is found, go to stage 4. Otherwise, move the head back to the front of the tape.
2. Scan the tape and mark the first 1 which has not been marked. If no unmarked 1 is found, reject
3. Move the head back to the front of the tape and go to stage 1.
4. Move the head back to the front of the tape. Scan the tape to see if any unmarked 1s remain. If none are found, accept; otherwise, reject.”
   After performing these algorithms if there is no strings for the relevant sizes given in question, then, it will come to default position and it will print a default output as 1.

But I am really not sure

Comment: This better fits at [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Dont you have to prove a Turing machine is undecidable?